# Why does this presave action code allow form to be saved when conditions are not met?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am having issue with the code for PreSaveAction on my SharePoint edit form. When the **Attainment Type** field equals Net new lines, I need to make the **Actual Attainment** field required.

I am using SP2013 Foundation. Attainment Type is a drop down field and Actual Attainment is a text field but it's numeric. The code below does not prevent the user from saving the Edit Form when the conditions exist.

Here is my code (I am using jquery-2.1.4.min.js & sputility.min.js):

```
    //form validation

    function PreSaveAction() {

    var attainment = SPUtility.GetSPField('Attainment Type');
    var attainmentValue = attainment.GetValue();
    var actual = SPUtility.GetSPField('Actual Attainment');
    var actualValue = actual.GetValue();

    if(attainmentValue=='Net new lines') {

        if(actualValue <= 0) {
        alert('Please enter the actual attainment at time of evalution.');
            return false;   
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also put an else{} field for if(attainmentValue =='Net new lines'). Function should return true if the attainmentValue is not net new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be SPUtility is seeing the value as a string perhaps. There also looks to be a typo in your function with your closures.

You are using jQuery, so there really isn't a need for SPUtility to get the data. Something like:

```
function PreSaveAction() {

  var attainmentValue = $("select[Title='Attainment Type']").val();
  var actualValue = $("input[Title='Actual Attainment']").val();
  console.log(typeof actualValue);

    if(attainmentValue=='Net new lines') {
      if(actualValue <= 0) {
        alert('Please enter the actual attainment at time of evalution.');
        return false;   
      }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```